# Can't change class in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
  $('.circleShape').click(function(){
    var colno = $(this).attr('class').substring(25, 30);
    for (var i = (cols-1); i >=0 ; i--) { //cols is a number of columns on the board
      if ($(colno).eq(i).hasClass('circleInitial')) {
        alert('old color');
        $(colno).eq(i).removeClass('circleInitial').addClass('circlePlayerOne');
        break;
      }
    }
  });
```

If any element of a column is clicked, I want to change the class of the lowest element in the same column that hasn't been changed yet. But $(colno) statement fails to grab the necessary element. How can I implement this? I started learning JS and jQuery just three days ago, so I can't figure out myself. 
This is a content of body in HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Welcome to Connect Four!</h1>
        <h3>The object of this game is to connect four of your chips in a row!</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
    <table id='board'>

    </table>
    <script src='js/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
    <script src='js/connect_four.js'></script>
  </body>
```

Actually, I generate the table in this way:

```
  function initBoard(){
  var chip = "<td class='chip'><div class='circleShape circleInitial'> </div></td>";
  var chips = Array(cols).fill(chip);
  chips = "<tr>" + chips + "/tr";
  $('#board').html(Array(rows).fill(chips));
  for (var i = 0; i < chipsTotal; i++) {
    var col='col' + (i%cols).toString();
    var row='row' + (~~(i/cols)).toString()
    $('.chip > div').eq(i).addClass(col).addClass(row);
  };
```

Comment: Paste your HTML too.

Comment: Please add your HTML markup too. Much better if you can create a working code snippet. or a JSFiddle

Comment: Always suspect your selectors. Check they return the elements you think they do by running `$(selector).length` - if it's 0, that's your problem; the element, as you're targeting it, doesn't exist. `colno` seems to be a string, so passing it to `$()` seems suspect.

Comment: @ Kiran Dash Sorry, I can't yet.

Comment: Without the contents of the `<table>` (even if only just enough to reproduce your problem) this question remains nonsensical and unanswerable: please, see the "*[mcve]*" guidelines to see what we need to see of your HTML, JavaScript/jQuery and so on.

Comment: @ David Thomas  I added the content generator function already,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of the clicked `td` and the last row of the `tbody`. Then match the index of the `tr`'s in the last row with the found index.

```js
$("td").click(function(){
 var index = $(this).index();
 var lastRow = $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').last();
 var colEnd = lastRow.find('td').eq(index);
 console.log(colEnd.text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Demo 1</td>
      <td>Demo 2</td>
      <td>Demo 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Demo 4</td>
      <td>Demo 5</td>
      <td>Demo 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Demo 7</td>
      <td>Demo 8</td>
      <td>Demo 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Demo 10</td>
      <td>Demo 11</td>
      <td>Demo 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Demo 13</td>
      <td>Demo 14</td>
      <td>Demo 15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your case write the above process in the click of `.circleShape` provided the rendered HTML has a similar structure.

```
$("table#board").on("click", ".circleShape", (function(){
 var index = $(this).index();
 var lastRow = $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').last();
 var colEnd = lastRow.find('td').eq(index);
 colEnd.removeClass('circleInitial').addClass('circlePlayerOne');
})
```

Comment: Could be of more help if you could post the generated HTML structure.

Comment: `<tr>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col0 row0"> </div></td>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col1 row0"> </div></td>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col2 row0"> </div></td>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col3 row0"> </div></td>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col4 row0"> </div></td>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col5 row0"> </div></td>
  <td class="chip"><div class="circleShape circleInitial col6 row0"> </div></td>
</tr>`   this way

Comment: Updated the answer.